# Wordpress: Read More Text For Mobile not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the read more script and it will display a button at the end with text showing less. the script is working fine but I've used the script in various sections and using the section class I've updated the read-more-text length as per my requirement. But when I show less it adds the inline CSS for the height of 100px, which is creating a problem for mobile devices for mobile to display the first paragraph I have added a large height, but after showing less it adds the 100px height as in line height.

Here is the script.

```
jQuery('.read-more__btn').click(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).siblings(".read-more__text").hasClass("show")){
    jQuery(this).removeClass("up");
    jQuery(this).text("Read More");
    jQuery(this).siblings(".read-more__text").animate({
        height: '100px'
    }, 1000);
    jQuery(this).siblings(".read-more__text").removeClass("show");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).siblings(".read-more__text").addClass("show");
    jQuery(this).siblings(".read-more__text").animate({
      height: jQuery(this).siblings(".read-more__text").get(0).scrollHeight
    }, 1000, function(){
      jQuery(this).height('auto');
    });
    jQuery(this).addClass("up");
    jQuery(this).text("Read Less");
  }
});
```

Comment: *"But when I show less it adds the inline CSS for the height of 100px, which is creating a problem for mobile devices for mobile to display the first paragraph I have added a large height,"* - so the problem is `100px` is too large for mobile? if so, perhaps you should use another unit such as `vh`, see [mdn on css values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

Comment: it's getting too long height if I use vh

Comment: dont use `100vh`, read the description on the documentation and adjust the value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below some basic examples for read more & less, might be it will help full for you.

```
<h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>
```

And [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_read_more) you can check example links